# Does Scrabble alllow inflection and agglutination in various languages?

Tags: scrabble

In English, words are pretty much independent dictionary units, though we do have "socks" alongside "sock", "agglomerator" alongside "agglomerate", and the like, but other languages have more flexibility in word variants.

In German, "little" can be kleiner, kleine, kleines, kleinen, kleinem; and "learn" can have [40 forms](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-treffen.html).

In Turkish,  evlerimden is made out of the parts [ev-ler-im-den](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9377/)  and means "from my houses."

In Yupik, [tuntussuqatarniksaitengqiggtuq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysynthetic_language) means "He had not yet said again that he was going to hunt reindeer."

(Of course, not all these necessarily have an official set of Scrabble rules, but they illustrate the variety that is possible.)

I ask because I want to play Scrabble in various languages like Hebrew or Yiddish where there are no official rules yet.

If you're familiar with non-English Scrabble: Are all possible forms of a word allowed in various language? Only a base form?

Comment: I'm French and yes, the French official scrabble dictionary contains all forms of all words. This makes some letters extremely valuable, for instance most words take an "s" in plural, so letter "s" can easily be added anywhere on the board.

Comment: The hard thing you'll have to do if you want to create a scrabble set in a new language is to determine the number of copies and value of each letter tile.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions#Hebrew for instance

Comment: Yes, all forms of a word are allowed, as long as they are "real" and not slang (but much slang becomes real after enough time & usage.)  That is fundamental to Scrabble. Hebrew has a far more interesting problem: vowels. Because vowels are not separate letters, a lot of words are much shorter than in other languages. Which could have significant effects on the number of Bingos and on game play in general.

Comment: Thank you @manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact. So in German, Turkish, and Yupik, in principle, all the above-mentioned would be allowed?

Comment: Yes. No reason not to allow the words.

Comment: @Stef -- Official Hebrew Scrabble has been sold for decades. So we have points and frequencies, which presumably are reasonable. But the rules in the box say nothing about conjugations, and attached prefixes  and suffixes (in Hebrew, some prepositions are attached so that the equivalent of "in water" for example, would  be "inwater", while "and your dog" would be "anddogyour". So I a trying to figure whether to allow those, and I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: This supports that approach https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25243